# Wordpress Theme with page slider

Tags: ajax, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I want to create a theme in which the website page slides out and slides in. I already have the website [link](http://bee-logical.com/software-solutions.php) which is not developed in wordpress. I am trying to create the exact same theme for the wordpress the functionality of sliding the page out and page in is the only issue. As we click on the navigation menu the complete page get refreshed can we avoid that and load the page body/content using ajax.? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code below works for me with posts:

```
$('a.ajax').click(function(event) {
          $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});               
                var post_url = $(this).attr("href") + ' #primary-ajax';
                nanobar.go(100);
                $("#portfolio-content").load(post_url,function(){
                   $(this).addClass('open');
                   $('body').removeClass('ajax-wait');  
                });          
          event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I just tested it for pages and it works too.

You will need to tweek it for you needs but this entirely possible!